# Using urllib2 with Jython 2.2

Tags: python, jython, urllib2, libraries

I'm working with a product that has a built-in Jython 2.2 instance.  It comes with none of the Python standard libraries.  When I run this instance of Jython, the default path is

```
['./run/Jython/Lib', './run/Jython', '__classpath__']
```

I added all of the .py module files from Python 2.2 to the ./run/Jython/Lib directory, and I am able to import them.  But I want to use urllib2 and I get this error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in ?
  File "./run/Jython/Lib/urllib2.py", line 90, in ?
  File "./run/Jython/Lib/socket.py", line 41, in ?
ImportError: no module named _socket
```

As far as I can tell, the _socket module is part of the Python lib-dynload libraries (_socket.so).  Can Jython use this file?  I tried putting it in my path, but it had no effect.

A Google search seems to tell me that others are able to use urllib and urllib2 with Jython 2.2, but I'm stuck  I have tried module libraries from older and newer versions of Python as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andy,

I got a clean Jython 2.2.1 install and ran the following script successfully.

```
$ ./jython
Jython 2.2.1 on java1.6.0_17
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
>>> print f.read(100)
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtm
>>>
```

I went back and checked the Meandre infrastructure code base. I have found that a minor modification was introduced into the path of the embedded Jython. However, that is not the main problem. The main issue is that I just realized that the Jython's system modules are missing on the Meandre distribution bundles.

You could fix it by manually copying the contents on the

```
<JYTHON_HOME>/lib
```

to

```
<MEANDRE_HOME>/run/Jython/Lib
```

and restart the server instance. Now the default modules should be available to the components of the infrastructure.

Just let me know if that gets you going and I will work on getting that fixed soon.